# post-excerpt not one of the options under screen options

Tags: metabox

I want to turn the post-excerpt function on but it doesn't even show as an option under 'screen options' for posts. How do I get it to display as a check box under screen options?

I have tried inserting the code...// Change what's hidden by default... into the function.php but this causes problems. Perhaps I am not inserting the code into the correct part of the file or something or have left something vital out?

Comment: It should be there by default unless you've done something to remove it.

Comment: Just set the site up last night and have done nothing apart from adding some plugins and content.

Answer (score 4):

Are you on the Edit *Post* Screen, or the Edit *Page* screen?

Pages do not support Excerpts by default, although you can enable it.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the only reason possible. To add exerpts for Pages, add the following line to your functions.php file:
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );

Comment: I'm on the Edit Post Screen

Comment: Oh I have it sorted, I was looking at the screen options on the main posts page. I just click on an individual post then screen options and there it is the excerpt option. Sorry to waste your time, but thanks for your help. It is there by default.

Comment: Glad it was something easy! :)

Comment: @Dee please post your solution as an answer and accept it.